# Java Array of Objects How to Access and Print

Tags: java, arrays, object, printing

I am entering data into two classes (Date and Task) that are array of objects (I believe that is what they are officially called) and part of a Day class.  I can add data to the Task class using the setter and I can add data to the Date class using the setter.  The question I have is how do I access that data entered into the Date and Task classes through the Day class that contains those objects.  I am using the Tester class to enter the data into these classes.  I can access and print the data for each date/task(s) combo right after I add the data to the classes by using the "System.out.println(day1);".  However, I can only print the last data I entered into the classes.  When I try to access the objects' data through the Day class, it is not showing anything.

I would expect my results to be the following:

```
2022/2/23
Description: Write code Hours: 2.5
Description: Research   Hours: 1.5
For a total of 4.0 hours.

2022/2/24
Description: Read code  Hours: 5.0
For a total of 5.0 hours.
```

But instead I just get the following error when I try to compile it using JGrasp:

```
Tester.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
      for (i=0; i < day1.length; i++) {
                        ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable day1 of type Day
Tester.java:29: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Task[]
         array = day1.getDate();
                             ^
2 errors
```

How do I print out/access the objects in the Day class?  I'm confused about how to do this in this context.  When I use "System.out.println(day1);" I was assuming it would print out both of the sets of data I entered into the classes, but only the most recent one printed.  I can print off the first data set entered by putting "System.out.println(day1);" after the first data set, but that is the only way it will print.  It almost seems like I am writing over the top of the first set of data I add with the second set of data.  Add to that I'm pretty unsure about how objects embedded within objects work. Thanks for your help!  Here is the code:

```
public class Day implements Comparable {
    public static final int MAX=50;
    private Task[] tasks;
    private int numTasks;
    Date myDate;
    Day myDay;
       
    public Day(int year, int month, int day) {
        myDate = new Date(year, month, day);
        tasks = new Task[MAX];
        numTasks = 0;
    }
    
    public void addTask(Task newTask) {
        tasks[numTasks] = newTask;
        numTasks++;
    }
    
    public int getNumTasks() {
        return numTasks;
    }
    
    public String getDate() {
        return myDate.toString();
    }
    
    public double getTotalHours() {
        int i;
        double sum;
        
        sum = 0;
        for (i=0; i < numTasks; i++)
            sum += tasks[i].getHours();
        return sum;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String result;
        int i;
        
        result = myDate.toString()+"\n";
        for (i=0; i < numTasks; i++) 
            result += tasks[i].toString()+"\n";
        result += "For a total of "+getTotalHours()+" hours.";
        return result;
    }
    //other getters and setters in this class too
}

public class Date implements Comparable {
    private int year, month, day;
    
    public Date (int inYear, int inMonth, int inDay) {
        year = inYear;
        month = inMonth;
        day = inDay;
        if (day > getNumDaysMonth(month, year) ||
            month < 1 || month > 12) {
            year = -1;
            month = -1;
            day = -1;
        }
        //other getters and setters below this
    }
}

public class Task implements Comparable{
   // field variables
   private String description;
   private double hours;
   // constructors -> initialize all field variables - specialized method
   public Task(String desc, double hrs) {
      description = desc;
      hours = hrs;
   }
   //other getters and setters below this
}

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Day day1;
      Task task1;
      Task array[];
      Day array2[];
      double totalHours;
      int n, i;
      
      day1 = new Day(2022, 2, 23);
      task1 = new Task("Write code", 2.5);
      day1.addTask(task1);
      task1 = new Task("Research", 1.5);
      day1.addTask(task1);
      
      n = day1.getNumTasks();
      System.out.println("Number of tasks = "+n);
      
      day1 = new Day(2022, 2, 24);
      task1 = new Task("Read code", 5.0);
      day1.addTask(task1);
      
      System.out.println(day1);
      System.out.println();
      
      for (i=0; i < day1.length; i++) {
         array = day1.getDate();
         System.out.println(array);
      }
      
      totalHours = day1.getTotalHours();
      System.out.println("Total hours = "+totalHours);
                 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning "day1.getDate()", which is a String, to "array", which is a task array. These are not compatible. All you need to do is `System.out.println(day1.getDate());` That would only print the same date day1.length times though. I suppose you want something from the day1 tasks. You probably want to implement a `Task Day.getTask(int index)` method to access them. It would be bad practice to return the whole task array, since the caller could then modify it. If you did want to implement a `Task[] Day.getTasks()` method, it should return a copy of the task array.

Comment: Thanks lbarowski for your help! I did something similar before I saw your post. In Tester, I changed `Day day1;` to `Day day[] = new Day[20];` and then wrote the data to the objects this way `day[0] = new Day(2022, 2, 23);`. That allowed me to set a location for the object so I could retrieve each day.